# Single call to top shows low CPU usage

Tags: linux, debian, cpu

I am running a test to measure CPU load on a machine running debian. 
For the test I've made a simple Python script that overloads all CPUs. 
Now, when running `top | grep Cpu(s)`, on the first call im getting around 5% usage (under 'us') and the next calls show the right usage- ~99%:
[image: example]

This is a problem for me as I need to use a script that periodically samples CPU on remote machines and if the first call is always low, I will always get bad samples.

Why does top give these wrong values? Is there a better way to achieve what I want?

Thank you.

Comment: That would because CPU1 is busy finding, loading and starting two new processes, which make a lot of kernel calls and cause a lot of interrupts and I/O waits. They are called "top" and "grep". As with quantum mechanics, you can't measure something without changing it. You might do better using: top -b -d 2 -n 2; and using the second block of output. This would eliminate the start-up activity, but not the collect-stats activity, in top.

Comment: That did it. Thank you very much :)
BTW I've found in the man page a comment saying the CPU% in top is relative from the latest call so I guess that's a reason.

Comment: Never seen the CPU as relative to previous. In particular, any time it decreases (and it can't increase forever), it would need to flash up a - sign. The %Cpu stats (us, sy, ni, id) add up to 100%, so at least one of them must always be negative relative to previous. Some things like vmstat have the first report as an average since reboot, and the rest for the current interval, so you always discard the first one. But it doesn't make sense for top, because you cant see the previous values to compare with.

Comment: Maybe I'm reading this wrong but from man top, section 2b : 

       2b. Line 2 shows CPU state percentages based on the interval since the
       last refresh.

Comment: I think it means the Cpu% are freshly averaged over the last delay interval, not that they show the numeric interval change between the latest view and the previous one. I just watched my Cpu in a tight loop and the Cpu rises to 100% and back down to idle in reasonable steps.